# NVIDIA GPU not being used for games (Kubuntu)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, games, gpu

I recently switched to Kubuntu with my laptop and I'm quite loving it for now. Only problem is my GPU: it seems that the OS recognizes it, but it's not using it when I want to play games (that are Proton/Linux compatible, i.e.: XCOM).

When typing *prime-select query*, it says "on-demand", which means, if I understood it correctly, that I can decide whether I want to use one GPU specifically for a program. Problem is, I don't have any options to do so when right-clicking the game.

I went into the nvidia settings through the *nvidia-settings* command, and change the prime profile to "Performance mode" and restarted my computer. Ooh boy, I shouldn't have: the loading screen got stuck and I needed to force restart (aka press the power button) to finally access the desktop. From there, I launched XCOM and it worked wonders (60 fps constant, and *watch nvidia-smi* showed that the game indeed used my GPU).

Restarted once again my desktop, and same problem. I managed to get access to my desktop, but everything was incredibly laggy.

I switched back to prime on demand setting, and since then the desktop is doing fine once again, but I'm back to square one: the game is still not using my GPU.

How can I force Steam games, or programs more generally (such as Blender if I decided to learn 3D for instance), to use the GPU and not the integrated graphic?

Thank you for your help

**EDIT**: Just tried the prime-run command, to force the program to use the dGPU. It says command not found.

Comment: Which kubuntu and which nvidia do you have?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include it: Kubuntu 21.10, Geforce RTX 3050 (laptop) and driver Nvidia 510

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I found a workaround but it's not optimal and it will be just a band aid until someone finds a proper answer.

To run Steam (and *in extenso*, games), I just added this command:

```
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __VK_LAYER_NV_optimus=NVIDIA_only __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia steam
```

Now, since Steam uses the proper GPU, games will as well. However, I'm still trying to understand how to tell Steam to uses only OpenGL, and games the Nvidia GPU.